# ActionBarsherlock issue in commonsware book

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, commonsware

In the commonsware book, tutorial #6, I am following the instructions to the letter.  I create the parallel directory having the contents of the \library directory from the zip download.  I make sure that the empublite project is at compliance lever 1.6.  I add the ActionBarSherlock to  the workspace and I get "Marker ID 170 not found" and I take note the the contents of the AndroidManifest.xml file has been cleared to zero.

I have read the other post here and reread all of the instructions.  The console error message is...

```
2012-07-21 16:53:32 - ActionBarSherlock] Parser exception for /ActionBarSherlock/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file.
```

what am I doing wrong?
thanks,
Dean

Comment: are you sure the file hasn't been truncated for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there's a flaw in the instructions.

If you are going to use Eclipse, do *not* put the source code for ActionBarSherlock directly in your workspace, which is what the instructions imply. When you bring the code into Eclipse, there will be a checkbox that you can check to "copy files to workspace" -- use that instead.

Eclipse does not like loading code that is not in an Eclipse project into an Eclipse workspace *where the code started in the workspace directory*. Just unpack `library/` someplace else temporarily (e.g., your desktop).

My apologies.

---

To quote [the errata notice I just filed](http://commonsware.com/Android/errata):

> Page 211 has incorrect Eclipse instructions for adding ActionBarSherlock. Skip the second paragraph of Step #1 ("For the purposes..."). Instead, unpack the `library/` directory somewhere away from your Eclipse workspace (e.g., on your desktop).

Comment: I ignored the second paragraph and copied the /Library contents into an empty directory named ActionBarSherlock located somewhere else on my d: drive.  I then followed your "To do that:" procedure on pp 212 creating a new project.  I get error dialog box saying Marker id 916 not found and two duplicate console messages saying "unable to resolve target "android-14".  many errors on the ActionBarSherlock exist - api level is at 15.  doing a clean has no effect.

Tried your "Note that if you use . . ." paragraph on 212 but it's not apparent how to download it from "github" (I don't get github).

Comment: @user1058647: "but it's not apparent how to download it from "github" (I don't get github)" -- either use `git` to clone the repository, or click on the ZIP button on the repository's home page to download a ZIP file or tarball. With respect to the rest, I will review the steps for setting up ActionBarSherlock as part of the rollout of Version 4.0 of my book, which should be released August 1st -- when you get the update, feel free to try that tutorial again.